# How to turn my javascript/React Native based app into .ipa for deployment?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, deployment

I currently have a starter app that is very basic but I am trying to upload it to test flight to test so that I can later upload new versions of my companies app.  I currently have your basic react native app using javascript.

I'm going to attempt to upload it to transporter and then upload that to test flight.  I'm having trouble converting my folder with the app in it to the required format (.ipa or .pkg).  Every tutorial I've seen uses xcode but I am writing my program in vs code with javascript.  How should I go about this?  I can't find any resources but I may be looking in the wrong places, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorials aren't using Xcode because it's their favorite IDE, they're using it because *you must* use Xcode to create any iOS build artifacts.

It's fine to use VS Code for writing code, but everything has to go through Xcode eventually. Make sure you've gone through [all the iOS setup](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup).

Comment: Oh okay I understand, so is there anything special I must do to upload my javascript app to xcode? Everytime I tried it won't let me select that folder as a project, I'm assuming because it is not an xcode file?

Comment: @Guitarman045 Check out the link I added to my answer. They have steps for working with an existing project.